# dynamic create table for data

Tags: jquery, dynamic

hi my friends How can I do make this example dynamic?

please look this picture

[image: http://s28.postimg.org/w2ff9w4ul/Ads_z.png]

I've done it but have not quite finished not working.
thank you

```
total 50 static count , Names are changing only

 var firstNames = ["Andrew", "Nancy", "Shelley", "Regina", "Yoshi", "Antoni", "Mayumi", "Ian", "Peter", "Lars", "Petra", "Martin", "Sven", "Elio", "Beate", "Cheryl","Michael","Guylene","George","michael","Elio","Sven","Ian","Martin","Yoshi","Guyline","Regina","Beate","Lars","Shelly","Elio","Petra","Cherly","Peter","Antoni","Steven","Adriana","Neomi","Brad","Anthony","Lary","Pit","Adriana","Norton","Daniel","Stefany","Pit","Ivan","Alicia","Demi"];




for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++) { // 5 rows

            dynamicTable += '<tr>';

            for (var n = 0; n < 10; n++)  // 10 cell
            { 
                var name = firstNames[0];// What index should I give here?

                dynamicTable += '<td>';

                dynamicTable += '<div id='+name+'>';

                dynamicTable +="<input type='checkbox' value='"+name+"'>name</input>";

                dynamicTable += '</div>';

                dynamicTable += '</td>';
            }
            dynamicTable += '</tr>';

        }

        dynamicTable += '</table>';
        $('#top-panel').append(dynamicTable);
```

Comment: What exactly **not working**?

Comment: var name = firstNames[0];// What index should I give here?  I don't know how to bind data..In each cell needs to add a name

Comment: `firstNames[(j * 10 + n)];`

Answer (score -1):

You just need a counter, that sets the index.

```
var dynamicTable;
var counter = 0;
var firstNames = ["Andrew", "Nancy", "Shelley", "Regina", "Yoshi", "Antoni", "Mayumi", "Ian", "Peter", "Lars", "Petra", "Martin", "Sven", "Elio", "Beate", "Cheryl","Michael","Guylene","George","michael","Elio","Sven","Ian","Martin","Yoshi","Guyline","Regina","Beate","Lars","Shelly","Elio","Petra","Cherly","Peter","Antoni","Steven","Adriana","Neomi","Brad","Anthony","Lary","Pit","Adriana","Norton","Daniel","Stefany","Pit","Ivan","Alicia","Demi"];

for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++) { // 5 rows
  dynamicTable += '<tr>';
  for (var n = 0; n < 10; n++)  // 10 cell
  { 
    var name = firstNames[counter];// What index should I give here?
    counter++;
    dynamicTable += '<td>';
    dynamicTable += '<div id='+name+'>';
    dynamicTable +="<input type='checkbox' value='"+name+"'>" + name + "</input>";
    dynamicTable += '</div>';
    dynamicTable += '</td>';
  }
  dynamicTable += '</tr>';
}
dynamicTable += '</table>';
$('#top-panel').append(dynamicTable);
```